# How are original SVM constraints checked and met in solving the dual problem?

Tags: svm

I understand the mathematics but I am confused about how the constraints $y_i(w^Tx_i+b)\geq 1−e_i$ are met during the process of training SVM. In formulating the dual problem, the constraints become $C>\alpha>0$, for $C$ is the regularization constant. I assume that this new constraint in the dual problem implies the original constraint so that in the process of training SVM the original constraints are met, but I couldn't quite figure out why this is so, if at all.

If my assumption is incorrect, then how can we check if the original constraints are met when training the SVM?